# How to autostart a JavaScript Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript

I am working on a webpage which will show the still images a from webcam and thus will need to refresh every 15 seconds.

I am trying to implement a countdown timer into my page to show when the page will refresh.

I have found this code on W3schools.com and have changed it to suit my needs but this countdown timer will only start after the user has pressed the start button. I am wondering how I need to change the script to make the timer start automatically when the page loads?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<script>
function timedText() {
var x = document.getElementById('txt');
var t1 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "15 seconds"},1000);
var t2 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "14 seconds"},2000);
var t3 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "13 seconds"},3000);
var t4 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "12 seconds"},4000);
var t5 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "11 seconds"},5000);
var t6 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "10 seconds"},6000);
var t7 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "9 seconds"},7000);
var t8 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "8 seconds"},8000);
var t9 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "7 seconds"},9000);
var t10 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "6 seconds"},10000);
var t11 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "5 seconds"},11000);
var t12 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "4 seconds"},12000);
var t13 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "3 seconds"},13000);
var t14 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "2 seconds"},14000);
var t15 = setTimeout(function(){x.value = "1 seconds"},15000);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="timedText()" />
<input type="text" id="txt" />
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: here is the Original code from my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
<TITLE>Local MDOT Cam's-KD8NXH's Page-- Superior Twp., Michigan</TITLE>
<link rel="icon" 
type="image/ico" 
href="http://www.qsl.net/k/kd8nxh/favicon.ico">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://www.qsl.net/k/kd8nxh/favicon.ico"       
type="image/icon"> <link rel="icon" href="http://www.qsl.net/k/kd8nxh/favicon.ico"  type="image/icon"> 
</head>
<body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(15000); timedText()">
<a href="http://www.qsl.net/kd8nxh/";"><img alt="" src="http://www.qsl.net/kd8nxh/BlueHomeButton.gif" style="width: 100px; height: 25px;" /></a>
<script>
window.onload = timedText;
function timedText() {
var txt = document.getElementById('txt'),
 counter = 15;
var timer = setInterval(function () {
 if(counter === 0) return clearInterval(timer);
 txt.value = counter + " seconds";
 counter--;
 }, 1000);
 }
```

---

Comment: Please don't use [*W3Schools*](http://www.w3fools.com).

Comment: ^ They are good for quick reference, but not for "teaching"
Apart from that, this code they give is bad design practice.  Consider using a loop for the timeout declarations.

Comment: @RobG Can you recommend a trustworthy source for code?

Comment: [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is a good, but the quality of articles varies greatly. They are getting better though. W3Schools has some OK content, but it pretends to be much more than it is. There's no substitute for reading widely. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put

```
window.onload = timedText;
```

in your script. This will run the `timedText` function once the page has loaded.

---

By the way, your code can be shortened significantly:

```js
window.onload = timedText;
function timedText() {
   var txt = document.getElementById('txt'),
     counter = 15;
   var timer = setInterval(function () {
     if(counter === 0) return clearInterval(timer);
     txt.value = counter + " seconds";
     counter--;
   }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt" />
```

Comment: I really don't want to have the start button at the beginning of the timer, can I just delete the last <form> section of the script?

Comment: @NoviceUbuntuGeek Yes, look at the example snippet, I have not included the `<form>` elements and it works as expected.

Comment: *setInterval* tends to drift, especially if the system is busy. For count down timers, it's better to use *setTimeout* and adjust the delay based on the time to just beyond the next full second.

Comment: I am still having problems with the code. when I implement it I get this on the webpage: `window.onload = timedText; function timedText() { var txt = document.getElementById('txt'), counter = 15; var timer = setInterval(function () { if(counter === 0) returnclearInterval(timer); txt.value = counter + " seconds"; counter--; }, 1000); }` I will edit my original post with the actual raw code from my page in question.

Comment: @NoviceCodingGeek For it to work you need the `<input type="text" id="txt" />` box somewhere on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this to your body tag:

```
<body onload="timedText()">
```

This will run immediately after the page has loaded

Answer (score 0):

Timeouts run at about the estimated time, not exactly. A good way to implement them is to use a function that calls itself every second using *setTimeout*, with small adjustments to the time based on the difference in the lag.

e.g. to count down use:

```
function countDown(seconds) {

  // Show the remaining seconds
  console.log(seconds);

  if (seconds > 0) {
    // Get time to just after next full second
    var lag = 1020 - new Date().getMilliseconds();
    setTimeout(function(){countDown(--seconds)}, lag);
  }
}

countDown(10);
```

The above can be improved by remembering the time that it's initiated and doing the count from there, I'll leave that to you. ;-)